# Capitalization edit does not render

Tags: bug, chat

I posted the word "IMac" in chat. Noticing my mistake, I edited to "iMac" but the rendered version was still "IMac"

Just to be sure, I entered edit mode again and sure enough, it was "iMac".

Seems like a bug where it isn't seeing an "actual" change when re-rendering.